# How to make zero's appear on left side?

Tags: c++

I am writing this program, in which we need to convert the input from the user from digits into words. I've written the whole program. The only error I am facing is that when I write e.g. 4200, the zeros aren't appearing. I am a beginner at C++.

```
while (num > 0)
{
    rem = num % 10;
    sum = sum * 10 + rem;
    num = num / 10;
}
num = sum;

while (num > 0)
{
    rem = num % 10;
    switch (rem)
    {
        case 1 :
            cout << "One " ;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Two " ;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Three " ;
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "Four " ;
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << "Five " ;
            break;
        case 6:
            cout << "Six " ;
            break;
        case 7:
            cout << "Seven "  ;
            break;
        case 8:
            cout << "Eight "  ;
            break;
        case 9:
            cout << "Nine "  ;
            break;
        case 0:
            cout << "Zero "  ;
            break;
```

Please help me out. How can I print the zeros too?

Comment: Please show the entire code.

Comment: I can't tell for sure without a minimal working example, but it looks like as some point `num` becomes zero, and the program terminates because it gets out of the two `while` loops. I'd try posting a complete reproduction example.

Comment: Your first loop effectively rewrites the number right-to-left, turning e.g. 123 into 321. That same loop turns 4200 into 0024 which is the same as 24. At this point, you can't tell anymore whether the original number was 42 or 420 or 4200 - you have lost information irretrievably. This approach isn't going to work.

Comment: Guys I'm currently a beginner at C ++ so if ya'll could make it more basic for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is not optimal. So, I have written a new solution.

## Solution

```cpp
int num;
cin >> num;
vector<string> v;

while (num > 0) {
    switch (num % 10) {
        case 1:
            v.push_back("One");
            break;
        case 2:
            v.push_back("Two");
            break;
        case 3:
            v.push_back("Three");
            break;
        case 4:
            v.push_back("Four");
            break;
        case 5:
            v.push_back("Five");
            break;
        case 6:
            v.push_back("Six");
            break;
        case 7:
            v.push_back("Seven");
            break;
        case 8:
            v.push_back("Eight");
            break;
        case 9:
            v.push_back("Nine");
            break;
        case 0:
            v.push_back("Zero");
            break;
    }
    num /= 10;
}
reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
for (auto a: v) cout << a << " ";
```

You also can use `map` instead of `switch`.
If you get any errors try to write `#include <vector>`.

## Very simple solution

```cpp
int num;
cin >> num;
string s;
while (num > 0) {
    switch (num % 10) {
        case 1:
            s = "One " + s;
            break;
        case 2:
            s = "Two " + s;
            break;
        case 3:
            s = "Three " + s;
            break;
        case 4:
            s = "Four " + s;
            break;
        case 5:
            s = "Five " + s;
            break;
        case 6:
            s = "Six " + s;
            break;
        case 7:
            s = "Seven " + s;
            break;
        case 8:
            s = "Eight " + s;
            break;
        case 9:
            s = "Nine " + s;
            break;
        case 0:
            s = "Zero " + s;
            break;
    }
    num /= 10;
}
cout << s;
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for your response but I am a beginner at C++ , so if you make it simpler. As I am a beginner.

Comment: Ok, I have edited my answer and added a new solution.

Comment: Why are you incrementing s

Comment: `s` is our output. I just insert a digit name to the beginning of `s`.

Comment: no the +s in each case, why?

Comment: Because we need to save other digits. For example `s` = "" and `num` = 52.
We get `2` and s = "Two " + s -> s = "Two ";
We get `5` and s = "Five " + s -> s = "Five Two"; Then print `s`.

Comment: So basically the string two is incremented and stored in s right? And how do you store in the left of the string s

Comment: We store current digit in left of string `s`.

Comment: For example “Five” -> “Two Five” -> “Eight Two Five” etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is simply to convert digits as-is into words, there is a much simpler approach:

```cpp
string input;
cin >> input;

for (char ch : input)
{
    switch (ch)
    {
        case '1':
            cout << "One " ;
            break;
        case '2':
            cout << "Two " ;
            break;
        case '3':
            cout << "Three " ;
            break;
        case '4':
            cout << "Four " ;
            break;
        case '5':
            cout << "Five " ;
            break;
        case '6':
            cout << "Six " ;
            break;
        case '7':
            cout << "Seven "  ;
            break;
        case '8':
            cout << "Eight "  ;
            break;
        case '9':
            cout << "Nine "  ;
            break;
        case '0':
            cout << "Zero "  ;
            break;
    }
}
```